# CSS - How to remove text off a screen when a checkbox is selected

Tags: css

I want to remove text off the screen when a checkbox is selected using CSS. I want to know if there's a way of doing this through CSS.  Here's some code

```
<form>
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
</form>

<p> sample text </p>
```

How do I remove the sample text when the checkbox is selected. I want to achieve this by using CSS.

**UPDATE**
It's not possible to do it through CSS, so can you tell me if there's a way to do this through JS.

Comment: can you show us what did you try to achieve that?

Comment: I don't know the solution to this, so I haven't done anything.

Comment: With this markup, it's not possible using CSS alone.

Comment: I recommend you visit this website https://www.w3schools.com/css/  to learn what is CSS capable of.

Comment: is there a way of doing this through js?

Comment: Sure js can do it, give it a try and update the question with the results if you failed to do it, so I help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with JavaScript:

```js
func = () => {
    if(document.querySelector("input").checked) {   
        document.querySelector("p").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("p").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" onchange="func()">
</form>
<p>Some Text</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can change the HTML to

```html
<form>
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    <p>sample text</p>
</form>
```

You could use adjacent sibling selector and the checked pseudo class.

```css
/* Remove entire p */
input:checked + p { display:none; }

/* Resize the font to zero */
input:checked + p { font-size: 0; }

/* Indent the text so it is offscreen */
input:checked + p { text-indent: -9999px; }
```

Comment: it works but I don't want the text to be inside the form. Thanks for trying to help out.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually achieve this result if you are able to change your structure a bit. You will need to put `input` and `p` tag together in the same `div` so we can target them with CSS.

html:

```html
    <form>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox">
        <p class="hello"> sample text </p> 
    </form>
```

css:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + p {
  display:none
}
```

Comment: no need for quotations in CSS3 for input type.

Answer (score 1):

Make a little change in your HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    <p id="home"> sample text </p>  <!-- added an id to the p tag -->
</form>
```

Create a JavaScript file, lets say 'main.js', inside write the code:

```
function change() {
    var decider = document.getElementById('check');
    if(decider.checked){
        document.getElementById('home').innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Add a script tag to link your JS file to the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```